# Como rodar um código fora de um diretório no Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Tentei rodar o código
[image: Código que quero rodar]

que está salvo na área de trabalho. No entanto, o Python Shell mostrou
[image: Mensagem de erro]

Poderiam me ajudar?

Obrigado,
Marcos Miotti

Comment: Veja a resposta neste *link*. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164960/cant-find-numpy-in-windows-8

Também não entendi ao certo a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instale o `numpy` através do *Miniconda*, utilizando o comando

```
conda install numpy
```

Depois disso, inclua o diretório do `numpy` na pasta do *Miniconda* utilizando o comando

```
sys.path.append(DIRETÓRIO)
```

Daí será possível fazer o `import numpy`, sem mensagens de erro :)

Marcos Miotti

Comment: O problema é que toda vez que tento importar o Numpy, aparece `Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there`. É por isso que faço isso.

Comment: Acima coloquei o *link* com outra pergunta que fiz, no StackOverFlow em inglês

Comment: Você está rodando seu código do diretório do código do Numpy, é isso Marcos? Se for, retire seu código e coloque em seu desktop, assim é bem capaz que funcione

Comment: Marcos, acabei de ver o seu último comentário no StackOverflow em inglês, para você rodar um código fora do diretório do numpy basta você salvar seu código no desktop e tentar executa-lo!

Comment: Não estava no diretório do Numpy. No entanto, mudei o código para minha área de trabalho e mesmo assim a mensagem acima apareceu.

Comment: Modifiquei minha pergunta, Vinicius. Veja lá.

Comment: Marcos, tente executar este código direto no SHELL Python, assim nós saberemos qual a origem do problema!

Comment: A mesma mensagem de erro aparece quando executo o código diretamente no Python Shell

Comment: Recomendo então que você reinstale o numpy, assim talvez resolva seu problema

Comment: SOLUÇÃO QUE ENCONTREI: adicionar ao `sys.path` o diretório do `numpy` que instalei com o *Miniconda*. Muito obrigado, Vinicius.